# What does memory-release Widget (or shortcut) do to get more available memory?

Tags: android, memory-management

Some widgets or shortcut can release memory to get more available.

How they do that?

Comment: clear's cache memory of most of the applications! there by freeing up some space.. (Doesn't make a huge difference though, IMHO)

Answer (score 4):

if you have android jelly bean or above from Gingerbird , you can free memory by run task manager and close those app which are running in background.

Comment: Would u like to give more details ? like how to close app in background, or should Service be closed ?

Comment: Every app has its own data in chache . for clearing this go to Application Manager,  select application and clear Data. This is general thing.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you're a web browser. You have a cache of images and so on in RAM. You release memory by clearing your cache and telling java to collect garbage:

```
fooCache.clear();
System.gc();
```